# How can i integrate prometheus in Scala sbt project?

Tags: scala, sbt, dropwizard, prometheus

I am trying to integrate prometheus for metrics in Scala sbt project? Can you guys please guide me how i achieve this.

Comment: I would suggest to use data dog it serves the same purpose and easy to use.

Answer (score 0):

One way (I haven't used it):
Kamon
http://kamon.io/documentation/1.x/reporters/prometheus/